# OpenJUMP Coordinate Transformation Plugin - where to find it in latest version

Tags: openjump

Recently I noticed a note by OpenJUMP dev team: **"Integration of Coordinate Transformation PlugIn in OpenJUMP core"**, which is great.

I could confirm that *Coordinate Transformation* menu, which was under *Plugin* of [OpenJUMP Snapshot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_snapshots/) `20170923-r5505-PLUS`, is not seen in `20171019-r5513-PLUS` anymore.

[image]
*r5505-PLUS*

[image]
*r5513-PLUS*

So it is definitely moved to somewhere. Now I am searching for this function in the latest `20171019-r5513-PLUS` (or `CORE`).

Comment: I don't have OJ available right now but logically it might belong to Tools - Edit geometries.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 No luck yet in `Edit geometries` and other sub-menus under `Tools`. It may have been renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snapshot r5522 it seems to be in two places. The first one opens with mouse-right button from the table of contents

[image]

In this version Coordinate Transformation seems to be added also back to Plugins but that is perhaps not intentional.